# how do i loop keys left and right in python using turtle

Tags: python, loops

## so i'm trying to loop the left and right keys to when i run the game code and press left or right i can hold left or right and the player moves left or right until i let off the key i'm using turtle

the code

```
enter code here
```

def move_left():

x = player.xcor()

x -= playerspeed

if x < -280:

x = -280

player.setx(x)

def move_right():

x = player.xcor()

x += playerspeed

if x > 280:

x = 280

player.setx(x)

def fire_bullet():

global bulletstate

if bulletstate == "ready":

winsound.PlaySound("stonks",winsound.SND_FILENAME |

winsound.SND_ASYNC)

bulletstate = "fire"

x = player.xcor()

y = player.ycor() + 10

bullet.setposition(x, y)

bullet.showturtle()

def iscollision(t1, t2):

distance = math.sqrt(math.pow(t1.xcor()-t2.xcor(),2)+math.pow(t1.ycor()-

t2.ycor(),2))

if distance < 15:

return True

else:

return False

turtle.listen()

turtle.onkey(move_left, "Left")

turtle.onkey(move_right, "Right")

turtle.onkey(fire_bullet, "space")

Comment: What's the issue? What's happening at the moment? I can see many syntax errors in the code, did you copy/paste the code from online somewhere?

Comment: Please edit the code and read this helpful link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask